# Controlling motors through python on raspberry pi from an android device

Tags: php, android, python, raspberry-pi3

I have recently started a project to build a small remote car controlled by android device. I have used raspberry pi 3 and L298 H board to control the motors. I have a simple python script on pi's apache server as follows

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import sys



def init();
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    gpio.setup(17,gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(22,gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(23,gpio.OUT)
    gpio.setup(24,gpio.OUT)

def forward();
    gpio.cleanup()    
    init();
    gpio.output(17,TRUE)
    gpio.output(22,FALSE)
    gpio.output(23,TRUE)
    gpio.output(24,FALSE)

forward()
time.sleep(4)
gpio.cleanup()
```

I recently started learning python, so I used a php file to connect Android to python using JSON. The php is as follows

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec("python runMotor.py");
?>
```

When I execute the php file from using ssh from my laptop, the motor runs well, but it does not work from my android app. Note that, when I try a simple python script to make file using f=open("file.txt","w+"), it works from the android well. Is there something I am missing needed to run GPIO pins over the network?

Comment: 2 years ago I made sort of the same thing, controlling the RPI GPIO over http (so web & android possible). I never finished it but maybe it helps you: [github link](https://github.com/washichi/RPIcontrol) keep in mind this was just practice and maybe not the best example of doing it :p.

Comment: Why used apache,PHP,shell and python ? You can do it only using Python. Check **WSGI** examples on `Python` !